# Boot Raspberry PI with Full Screen Epiphany Browser & Disable Screen Sleep

Tags: noobs, web-browsers, raspi-config

I am trying to display reports on a LCD using Raspberry PI with following requirements:

- When Raspberry PI is turned on the Epiphany Browser automatically opens a pre-configured    URL in full Screen Mode.
- The display shouldn't go to sleep.

I am using B+ series Model of Raspberry PI with NOOBS.

So far I am able to configure PI to open Epiphany Browser with a pre-configured URL loaded in it. But I am unable to do it in full-screen mode. Secondly my display goes to sleep after some time. I have done following configuration at:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
as

#@lxpanel --profile LXDE
#@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
#@xscreensaver -no-splash

@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@epiphany-browser http://10.10.2.70/myreport
@sleep 2s
@echo key F11 | xte -x:0
```

Kindly guide me how to proceed with this configuration to achieve my goal of displaying web page in full-screen mode on start-up and disabling of display sleep.

Comment: You have asked two completely separate questions here.  One of them already has an answer and the other one is off topic (but if you bother to search online about it, I'm sure you can quickly solve that, [here's a hint](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/epiphany1.html), and as a further clue, if you press Ctrl-F, your browser will probably let you search a web page for a specific phrase!!).

Comment: you have no right to assume that i haven't searched already. I have tried many options and none of them worked, that's why i posted the query here. If you can't provide a useful answer than don't comment and bully others with your 8k points.

Comment: I can see just by looking at what you have that you did not use the `-f` option clearly listed at the top of the epiphany manual page.  If it does not work, then you should be asking why epiphany's full screen mode does not work on [Unix & Linux Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), since it is not a pi specific piece of software.  BTW, I am not blaming you for not finding the duplicate of the other question; I left that comment to explain that it is **one question at a time**.  Hopefully the purpose and value of that is intuitable.

Comment: Another quick online search reveals that epiphany has a "Help" feature.  If you have tried various things from the documentation, then when you ask your *specific, singular* question at U&L, **make sure you mention all of them explicitly so other people do not waste their time making suggestions you have already tried.**

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: @goldilocks: point noted, next time i will be more elaborate in my questions. Thank you for the shared links.